# Concatenate two DataFrames via column [PySpark]

Tags: dataframe, merge, pyspark, concatenation

I have two columns, i.e. (both with the same number of entries per column)

```
df1 =
+-------+
| col1  |
+-------+
|   10  |
+-------+
|   3   |
+-------+
...
df2 = 
+-------+
| col2  |
+-------+
|   6   |
+-------+
|   1   |
+-------+
...
```

I wish to merge them such that the final DataFrame is of the following shape:

```
df3 =
+-------+-------+
| col1  | col2  |
+-------+-------+
| 10    | 6     |
+-------+-------+
| 3     | 1     |
+-------+-------+
...
```

But I am not able to do so with the `join` method since I am not attempting to merge columns based on column header. If anybody has any tips on how to achieve this easily that would be greatly helpful!

Comment: Check this,https://forums.databricks.com/questions/8180/how-to-merge-two-data-frames-column-wise-in-apache.html

Comment: You might be interested in this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883151/how-to-retrieve-a-column-from-pyspark-dataframe-and-and-insert-it-as-new-column/45884807#45884807

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this if you are able to get your columns as list is to use python `zip` method. For example:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = ['foo','baz','bar']
data_tuples = list(zip(list1,list2))
df = spark.createDataFrame(data_tuples)
df.show()

+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  1|foo|
|  2|baz|
|  3|bar|
+---+---+
```

However I'm not sure how it behave with big dataset.

Answer (score -1):

try this

`df1 = df1.withColumn("code", monotonically_increasing_id())`

`df2 = df2.withColumn("code", monotonically_increasing_id())`

this way you give them both a column `code` which you can use to classically merge both df's with.

`df3 = df2.join(df1, ["code"])`